# Pass Decryption Algorithm into MySql select statement

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

Hi I have some encrypted fields in my MySql database that I would like to decrypt while calling the SELECT statement. My decryption algorithm looks something like $cipher->decryptThis('string to decrypt').. How can I pass this into the SELECT query so that my results are decrypted data. I have done something like this;

```
SELECT id,date,$cipher->decryptThis(patientAddress) FROM renal_apptRequest"
```

but to no avail. There must be something I'm missing please point me in that direction. Thanks!

Comment: If your $cipher is a PHP class, you can't inject it directly into a SQL statement: you need to select the encrypted data, then decrypt it in PHP

Comment: I suspect you'd also need to provide a key to decrypt any data

Comment: I am using a phpgrid plugin to display the data to the browser, so in order to display decrypted data i need to decrypt it in the `SELECT` else the grid would render encrypted data

Comment: I think you're asking the impossible, if your $cipher is a PHP class, you can't inject it into the SELECT. What algorithm is being used for the encryption in the database?

Comment: The key has already been taken care of.. the decryption works normally on encrypted data but after they have already been rendered.

Comment: The Rijndael cipher is AES, so you could probably use MySQL's built-in AES_DECRYPT

Answer (score 0):

If your decryption/encryption algorithm is written in PHP and has no native-MySQL equivalent (i.e. DES_DECRYPT or AES_DECRYPT) you will need to receive the data from the SQL and then post-process it (after receiving it).

Comment: It seems the data is in a column named `patientAddress`, encrypted, and he wants a single select statement to get it out and decrypted. I don't know anything about your case suggestion, but I don't think your alternative is oriented towards that; it looks more like you're decrypting something to make it input to the select.

Comment: HASH was an EXAMPLE, not saying it is the same, I just didn't want to use AES_DECRYPT or DES_DECRYPT, they are harder to give an example for

Comment: I am using a phpgrid plugin to display the data to the browser, so in order to display decrypted data i need to decrypt it in the SELECT else the grid would render encrypted data